# How to use javascript script in html code in local

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My code in jsfiddle is working but when I try to use it in local it doesn't.
I don't know how to fix it because i think that the code is right.
I tried also to download the Jquery file and I linked it in the code but it doesn't working. I'm sure that is a stupid error, but I don't know how to solve it.

Working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4a5qaLud/)

My prova.php file:

```
<html lang="it">
      <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
        </head>
        <script type="text/javascript">

$('#btn').click(function() {
  var primo = document.getElementById('faketxt');
  var wordLimit = 145;
  var words = primo.textContent.replace(/(&lt;([^&gt;]+)&gt;)/ig,"").split(/\s/);
  if (words.length) {
    var count = 0;
    var div = createDiv();
    words.forEach(function(word) {
      if (++count > wordLimit) {
        count = 1;
        div = createDiv();
      }
      if (div.innerHTML) {
        div.append(' ');
      }
      div.append(word);
    });
  }
});

function createDiv() {
  div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'fakes';
  document.getElementById('boxes').append(div);
  return div;
}

        </script> 
        <body>
<div id="faketxt" contenteditable>Write Here</div>
<button id='btn'>OK</button> <br>
<div id='boxes'>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

My style.css:

```
#faketxt {
  -moz-appearance: textfield-multiline;
  -webkit-appearance: textarea;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 28px;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 2px;
  resize: both;
  width: 400px;
}

.fakes {
  width: 150px;
  height: 300px;
  font-size: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

#boxes {
  display: flex;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: what error is found in console?

Comment: I can't see any errors in the console by default, there is a way to see them?

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi Try console.log in various places of your js code; e.g. in click event.

Comment: right click and inspect element..then click on console tab.

Comment: No erros, and it seems like that jquery library is loaded, from sources.

Comment: If jquery hadn't been loaded then you'd have got error in console. You can type `jQuery` then press enter to double check.

Comment: @user31782 If I type "jQuery", it displays this 
"
function (a,b){return new r.fn.init(a,b)}"

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi Yes its there. jquery is loaded. Try copy pasting whole js code in console. Then you'd either get the page working or it will throw some error.

Comment: Yes, It's working only if I paste my js code in the console, but why? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Which browser do you use? are you using a local server or just double click on HTML file?

Comment: @MohamedNoor I'm just clicking on Html file...

Comment: I think that's why, try to use a local server (wamp for example: http://www.wampserver.com/en/), or run the file using Google Chrome, but most likely you need a local server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because your html is after js code. Put the js code after the html code or put it in dom ready.

What is happening is when your javascript code executes there is no `#btn`, no `#faketxt` and no `#boxes`. So the `$("#btn")` declared before `<button id="btn"></button>` returns an empty string because there is no element matched by it.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much!

Comment: the downvote isn't mine

Comment: @NiccolòGuidi No worries : ) glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Answers:

1:
You linked a file with '//' like '//code.jquery.com'. Fix it:
Replace '//' with 'http://'

2:
Are you sure your CSS file is linked correctly? Maybe the file inside a subfolder css. Fix it: '/css/style.css'

Comment: The jquery library is loaded and my css is linked correctly :) but it still doesn't working , look at the comments above